# How to get rid of white space without breaking words?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a paragraph to fit the width of a text however, I am getting this white space on line breaks. I am looking for any solution that wouldn't affect text and wouldn't require JavaScript (that could cause a reflow). Doesn't have to be inline-block.

```css
* {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div {
    background: gray;
}
p {
    background:white;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    <p>technique and statement a landscape or discovery a injection or fic</p>
</div>
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrjz2c8b/)

Is there any way that I can make paragraph width match the width of the longest line?

Here is the expected and current result:
[image: White space problem]

Comment: There is only one line.

Comment: @James I have added an image that shows expected and current result

Comment: you should decrease max-width than.

Comment: "match the longest line" - as @James said, there is only one line. You are artificially making line wraps with the max-width. You either need to put real line wraps into the text, or continue to adjust the max-width.

Comment: that might be because of max widh property. use width 100% instead.  you container is more than 130px might be the case or use max width in the container instead

Comment: I think @skyline3000 is right and the only solution is to give manual line breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @skyline3000 mentioned:

> "match the longest line" - as @James said, there is only one line. You are artificially making line wraps with the max-width. You either need to put real line wraps into the text, or continue to adjust the max-width.

You need to manually specify line breaks which work for me - handling line breaks is rather an easy job for regular users.

```css
body {
    background: gray;
}
#container {
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
span {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    max-width: 130px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
    <span>technique and<br>statement alandscape<br> ordiscovery ainjectn or
fic i</span>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzvybhd4/)

Also, I have decided to move to the span element and wrap it into display: inline-block to achieve this result. I don't know if this result is satisfying to you, I'm not sure if I was trying to fight HTML/CSS spec here. Real line breaks are probably the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
div {
    background: gray;
    max-width: 130px; // you can ignore this if you dont need to be 130 px
}
p {
    background:white;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer please.

Comment: that might be because of max widh property. use width 100% instead. you container is more than 130px might be the case or use max width in the container instead